# Requiring base class operator to perform a "domain check" (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Let's say I'm trying to define an abstract base class for "mathematical functions" - i.e. things that look like `y=f(x)` where both `x` and `y` are numeric types, and `x` is in the "domain" of `f`.  Here's what my abstract base class might look like:

```
template<typename T>
class AbstractFunction{
public:
    virtual bool CheckDomain(T) const = 0;
    virtual T operator()(T) const = 0;
};
```

This says that any concrete class derived from `AbstractFunction` must implement a `CheckDomain` method and an "evaluation operator" `()`.  Now what I'd like to do is *require* that the evaluation operator calls the `CheckDomain` function before evaluating the function.  Is there a neat way to do some sort of "partial implementation" for `operator()(T)`?  Obviously this would mean it's no longer a pure virtual.

I thought I had it figured out with the following construction, but I must be missing something because if I create `ConcreteFunction f` and try to evaluate `f(1.0)`, it doesn't use the derived class methods (it always returns 0 for `CheckDomain(x)`).

```
class AbstractFunction{
    public:
        virtual bool CheckDomain(double) const = 0;
        virtual double EvalFunction(double) const = 0;
        virtual double operator()(double);
};

double AbstractFunction::operator()(double x){
    bool D = CheckDomain(x);
    if(D==1){
        return EvalFunction(x);
    }
    else{
        std::runtime_error("Error: Out of Domain");
    }
}

class ConcreteFunction : public AbstractFunction{
    public:
        bool CheckDomain(double x) const {(x>0.0)? 1:0;}
        double EvalFunction(double x) const {return x*x;}
        // Don't need to define operator(), should inherit from AbstractFunction.
};
```

I'm sure I'm missing something easy, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my method works!  I just spaced out on my definition of `ConcreteFunction::CheckDomain`.  I did the domain check, but didn't return it!  The following code compiles and runs as desired:

```
#include<stdexcept>
#include<iostream>

class AbstractFunction{
    public:
        virtual bool CheckDomain(double) const = 0;
        virtual double EvalFunction(double) const = 0;
        virtual double operator()(double) const;
};

double AbstractFunction::operator()(double x) const{
    bool D = CheckDomain(x);
    if(D==1){
        return EvalFunction(x);
    }
    else{
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: Out of Domain");
    }
}

class ConcreteFunction : public AbstractFunction{
    public:
        bool CheckDomain(double x) const {return (x>0.0)? 1:0;}
        double EvalFunction(double x) const {return x*x;}
        // Don't need to define operator(), should inherit from AbstractFunction.
};  

int main()
{
    ConcreteFunction f;
    std::cout<<"f(1) = "<<f(2.0)<<std::endl; //OK, returns 4
    std::cout<<"f(-1) = "<<f(-1.0)<<std::endl; //Throws runtime error, out of domain.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that `D==1` comparison is ugly - use `true/false` if you must compare a bool to something. Better, just write `if (D)`. Best: write `if (CheckDomain(x)) ...`. Oh, and you probably want `EvalFunction ` to be protected, since it shouldn't be called directly by client code.

Comment: Oh, and another one: your CheckDomain can just be `{ return x > 0.0; }`.